# Dynamic number of input widgets in shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I want to write an app that reads in the uploaded data, then puts enough `numericInput` due to the number of unique elements in a column (the name of the columns is Big). This question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35579439/dynamic-number-of-sliders-in-shiny) helped me.

The code is as below:

```
library(shiny)
 ui <- fluidPage(
  fileInput(inputId = "up","", accept = '.csv'),
  uiOutput("sliders")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  INPUT <- reactive({
    infile <- input$up

    #validate(need(input$up, "Input a valid filepath."))      

    read.csv(infile$datapath, header = TRUE, sep = ",")
  })

 inVars <- reactive({
    unique(INPUT()$Big)
  })

  output$sliders <- renderUI({
    pvars <- length(inVars())
    lapply(seq(pvars), function(i) {
      numericInput(inputId = paste0("range", pvars[i]),label = pvars[i],value = 1)
    })
  })

}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Three questions:

**1.** When I put

```
if (is.null(infile))
return(NULL)
```

instead of `validate`, it gives me an error which looks like this:

`missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed`

What should I do to get rid of this error?

**2.** How could I add a label for each one of the `numericInput`?

**3.** How could I use the input values later? In a `reactive` environment?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not with the `if (is.null(infile))` statement, it is with the `lapply` function. When the Shiny app just starts, the entire `server` function is executed, the length of `inVars()` is `0` and the sequence `seq(pvars)` will be `1` `0`. Then the `numericInput` will fail because you are making a reference to `pvars[i]` when `i` is equal to `0`.

Below is the code that fixes the problem and also answers your questions.

```R
library(shiny)
 ui <- fluidPage(
  fileInput(inputId = "up","", accept = '.csv'),
  uiOutput("sliders")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  INPUT <- reactive({
    infile <- input$up
    if (is.null(infile))
      return(NULL)
    read.csv(infile$datapath, header = TRUE, sep = ",")
  })

 inVars <- reactive({
    unique(INPUT()$Big)
  })

  output$sliders <- renderUI({
    pvars <- length(inVars())
    if (pvars > 0) {
      div(
        lapply(seq(pvars), function(i) {
          numericInput(inputId = paste0("range", inVars()[i]),label = inVars()[i],value = 1)
        }),
        actionButton("getValues", "Get values"),
        tableOutput('table')
      )
    }
  })

  values <- 0

  # get the values of each numericInput and store them in "values"
  observeEvent(input$getValues, {
      # initialize vector 
      values <<- rep(NA, length(inVars()))
      names(values) <<- inVars()

      for(k in 1:length(inVars())) { 
        inputName <- paste0("range", inVars()[k])
        # only get a value if the numeric input exists
        if (!is.null(inputName))
          values[[k]] <<- input[[inputName]]
      }
    # show values as a table
    output$table <- renderTable(data.frame(
                        variable = inVars(),
                        values))

  })

}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

**Update:**

To test the code, use a .csv file with content like:

```
num,Big
1,a
2,a
3,b
4,b
5,c
6,c
7,d
8,d
```

Screenshot:

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: This does not work. I added `dataTableOutput("table")` in `ui` but still not working. Also, I want to automatically read the values without and action button.

Comment: It should work with `tableOutput`, I updated the answer with the input data used to test and a screenshot, please check you have the last version of Shiny. If you want to automatically read the values you can review the solution in https://stackoverflow.com/a/40643541/4322318

Comment: There is one problem with your code that I can't figure it out. If you change the value of `d`, the value of `c` will change. When I ran your code for the first time with different dataset, an error came up: `arguments imply differing number of rows: 4, 5`. It seems something is wrong inside the `observeEvent`.

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce the error you mention of changing the value of `d` by changing `c`. Related to the second problem, the code was just as an example for a very specific input data, it seems that the problem is because it is expecting a dataset  with a column named `Big`.

Comment: In the `numericInput`, change the value for `C`, and press the get values. Although you change the value of `C` the value of `D` changes.

Comment: I found the issue and edited in your response. It kept saving in the wrong place.