# Dynamically update position of sliderInput in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I have the following code to dynamically make either Check Boxes or Sliders.

```
 server <- shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
  # define the data frame to use
  dat <- mtcars
  dat <- rownames_to_column(dat, "car")
  # name of availale data frame
  varNames <-  names(dat)
  # define defaul values as the first value in each column
  defaultValues <- as.numeric(dat[1,])
  # store the selected variable in a reactive variable 


  # dynamically creates a set of sliders
  output$controls <- renderUI({
    div(
      fluidRow(
        column(9, uiOutput("rangeUI"))
      )
    )
  })

output$rangeUI <- renderUI({
 lapply(1:length(varNames), function(k) {
   fluidRow(
     column(12,
           if (is_character(dat[1, k])) {
             # a slider range will created only is the variable is selected


             checkboxGroupInput(paste0("slider_", varNames[k]), label = varNames[k], choices = unique(dat[[k]]), selected = NULL,
                                inline = FALSE, width = NULL, choiceNames = NULL, choiceValues = NULL)
           } else {
             # otherwise uses single value with a default value
             sliderInput(paste0("slider_", varNames[k]), label = varNames[k], 
                         min = 0, max = 100, value = defaultValues[k])
           }
    )
  )
 })
})
```

The issue I am running into is that I would like to display the sliders and check boxes side by side until they hit the screen width and then start a new row. Currently, they are all in one column.

Is there a good way to dynamically adjust `offset` to accomplish this, maybe something like this?

```
column(12, offset = match(k, colnames(dat)), # then lead into the if else statement
```

Any other suggestions on building the UI are welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to put the `fluidRow` outside the `lapply` and change the size of the column from `12` to maybe `3`, otherwise you are creating multiple rows with only one column, instead on one row with multiple columns.

Below is your code modified, maybe it could help you.

```R
library(shiny)
library(tibble)
ui <- fluidPage(
  uiOutput("controls")
)

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
  # define the data frame to use
  dat <- mtcars
  dat <- rownames_to_column(dat, "car")
  # name of availale data frame
  varNames <-  names(dat)
  # define defaul values as the first value in each column
  defaultValues <- as.numeric(dat[1,])
  # store the selected variable in a reactive variable 

  # dynamically creates a set of sliders
  output$controls <- renderUI({
    fluidRow(
      column(offset = 3, 9, uiOutput("rangeUI"))
    )
  })
  # to test that a dynamically created input works with an observer
  observeEvent(input$slider_mpg, {
    cat("slider_mpg:", input$slider_mpg, "\n")
  })
  output$rangeUI <- renderUI({
    fluidRow(
      lapply(1:length(varNames), function(k) {
        column(3,
          if (is.character(dat[1, k])) {
            # a slider range will created only is the variable is selected
            checkboxGroupInput(paste0("slider_", varNames[k]), label = varNames[k], choices = unique(dat[[k]]), selected = NULL,
                              inline = FALSE, width = NULL, choiceNames = NULL, choiceValues = NULL)
          } else {
            # otherwise uses single value with a default value
            sliderInput(paste0("slider_", varNames[k]), label = varNames[k], 
                       min = 0, max = 100, value = defaultValues[k])
          }
        )
      })
    )
  })
})

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

**Update:**

You can get the values of dynamically created inputs by using an action button as is explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45202844/4322318) or get them automatically by using the solution explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40643541/4322318).

Comment: Thanks, this was helpful. If I want to update a chart using all of the dynamically created sliderInput options, is there a way to reference those values? `input$slider_mpg` where slider_mpg is an inputId does not seem to work on the dynamically created sliders.

Comment: I updated the solution to show that you can use an observer to get the value of `input$slider_mpg`. Also I included some links to get the values. Please consider to accept the answer by clicking on the check mark.